# Get additional product attribute separately

Tags: template, product-attribute

How to get additional product attribute separately in the product view template?

`$this->getAdditionalData()` - is used in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`.

It returns an array with all additional attributes.

I want to know if it is possible to get a single additional attribute, created by me in admin, without loading the whole array and having to do a `foreach()` .

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$attributeCode = 'your_attribute_code_here';
$value = $this->getProduct()->getData($attributeCode);
```

or if it's a dropdown or multiselect and you want the labels

```
$label = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
```

Comment: I have a multiple select. Is it possible to get the single values somehow in an array? Thanks!